# Extra columns in the middle of existing columns pipe delimited text file (How to ignore that column values in flat file source ) SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl

I have used SSIS package flat file source to read pipe delimited | text file and used column delimiter as | and text qualifier as none. I need to handle that if extra columns in the source file need to skip that column values.

If new columns are in the source file the data get loaded into wrong columns. How to skip the values of that rows?

Comment: Are these extra columns anywhere in the row or at the end?

Comment: It comes anywhere. We cant able to assume that it will come in end.

Comment: Sorry, misread this comment.  If extra columns come anywhere in the file, you'd have to write a script component to read the file and script rows with extra content.  I'll add another answer for that

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:  I revised the answer to remove rows with more than the expected number of columns:

Parse it with an SSIS with a script component source.  In the script component:

-Select the flat file connection manager under connection managers, below I left it named "Connection"

-Add columns to the output buffer and configure their data types.  In my example, they are named "First" and "Second"

-In the script, add a reference to System.IO and do something like the following which looks for an expected number of columns and only adds a row to the buffer if it meets that criteria:

```
using System.IO;
...
public override void CreateNewOutputRows()
{
    var expectedNumOfColumns = 2;
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Connections.Connection.ConnectionString))
    {
        string line;
        while((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            var parsedLine = line.Split(',');
            if (parsedLine.Length == expectedNumOfColumns)
            {
                Output0Buffer.AddRow();
                Output0Buffer.First = parsedLine[0];
                Output0Buffer.Second = parsedLine[1];
            }
        }
    }
}
```